# Variable scope JavaScript - events

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I only have one question. If I put this line of code `let guess = document.querySelector(".number").value;` out of function, the program will not work for me.
Here is complete code:

```js
let label = document.querySelector(".label");
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener('click', function() {
  let number = document.querySelector(".number").value;
  label.textContent = number;
});
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
<input type="number" class="number">
<label class="label">label</label>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly, what is your question?

Comment: Or check the `script` tag order

Answer (score 1):

When the script loaded its get executed. So, if you put `let number = document.querySelector(".number").value;` out of the event listener function, it will be executed when your input field has nothing. So `number` variable will have empty string. Your event listeners will be executed whenever their respective event is triggered. So at that time your input field might have some actual input.

Answer (score -1):

In your script, you should try this.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
       document.querySelector(".button").onclick = function () { 
          let number = document.querySelector(".number").value;
              document.querySelector(".label").textContent = number;
       };
    }
</script>
```

Test:

```js
document.querySelector(".button").onclick = function () { 
    let number = document.querySelector(".number").value;
    document.querySelector(".label").textContent = number;
};
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
<input type="number" class="number">
<label class="label">label</label>
```